# Why don't these Java replaceAll statements work?

Tags: java, regex, string

```
String level = "INFO";
String stamp = "2013-04-26";
String message = "Log me, please!";

String template = "[%LVL%] - %STAMP%\n%MSG%";
String log = template.replaceAll("%LVL%", level);
log = template.replaceAll("%STAMP%", stamp);
log = template.replaceAll("%MSG%", message);

System.out.println(log);
```

This prints:

```
[%LVL%] - %STAMP%
Log me, please!
```

Why does the 3rd `replaceAll("%MSG%", message);` work, but the first 2 don't?

Comment: Maybe different character code;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're not using the replaced variable in the other statements. You always use `template`, so you'll alway replace the original template variable, not the (incrementally) replaced ones. So in the end, you'll just have the original `template` replaced with the `%MSG%` pattern.

It should read:

```
String log = template.replaceAll("%LVL%", level);
log = log.replaceAll("%STAMP%", stamp);
log = log.replaceAll("%MSG%", message);
```

**Edit**

As @Fildor suggests, `String.format()` would be an even better solution:

```
String.format("%s - %s\n%s", level, stamp, message);
```

Comment: A little off topic: @TicketMonster Why don't you use `String.format`?

Comment: Agree. It would be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

`replaceAll` return the resulting string but doesnt modify the original string. You need to use  `log = log.replaceAll` for the future statements.